# Problem seeing Data from reference input (SQL) Azure Stream Analytics

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure, azure-stream-analytics

I am trying to preview the data coming from a SQL DB that is set as a reference input for my Azure stream analytics job.

I am getting this error:
`We cannot locate the resource for the selected input. Please make sure its subscription has been selected in the global subscription filter.`

I have looked online but can't seem to find how to resolve it.

I also have data coming from an event hub and that is working, error occurs only when previewing DB data.

Comment: hi,does my answer helps you?

Answer (score 0):

> We cannot locate the resource for the selected input. Please make sure
>   its subscription has been selected in the global subscription filter.

I can't reproduce your issue on my side.But based on above issue,i think you have multiple subscriptions. You could try to make sure the subscription (which your sql db resides in) has been selected in the global subscription filter.

Step is navigating to Subscription Management Page in the portal and check whether the subscription is selected with global subscription filter.It not,select it in the right box.

[image]

Add a reference for you :https://www.kunal-chowdhury.com/2018/06/azure-global-subscription-filter.html